# simon says game java android

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner on java and android, and now I'm trying to program the "simon says" game to learn this language, but this doesn't works fine.  :-(

The first and most important problem: When I try to show the sequence of colors [number 1 to 4] stored in the array seq[] with the method seq_show().... ho call but_show(x) to change the background color of each button... But I can't see the change of the backgroud color of the corresponding linearlayout... 
Also I has erased the READY? source code button because is not closed before seq_show().

I do not understand this java's way to program... is not line by line, step by step... I thing is by threads and I do not understand where the pointer of the executed code is. :-(

Can someone help me ?

Then, in the method seq_input() I catch the click's on the LinearLayout... and I thing this runs fine... but I need to solve the seq_show() problem first to continue with the program.

thanks !!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public LinearLayout l1, l2, l3, l4;
public GestureDetector gd1,gd2,gd3,gd4;
public static int seq[] = new int[25]; 
public int seq_pos = 0; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Array pos[] amb 25 clics del joc simon 
    //
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        seq[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
    }


    // declaració 4 onClickListener
    //
    l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_green);
    l1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            seq_input(1);
        }
    });

    l2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_red);
    l2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            seq_input(2);
        }
    });
    l3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_yellow);
    l3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            seq_input(3);
        }
    });
    l4 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_blue);
    l4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            seq_input(4);
        }
    });

    seq_show(0);
}


// Mostra la sequencia de botons a pulsar
//
public void seq_show(int seq_end) {
    for (int i=0; i <= seq_end; i++){

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        but_show(seq[i]);
    }
 }


// Espera la pulsació de la sequencia de botons
//
public void seq_input(int but_pushed){
    if (seq[seq_pos] == but_pushed) {
        seq_pos++;
        but_show(seq[but_pushed]);

        seq_show(seq_pos);

    }else{

        MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wrong);
        sound.start();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                }
        }, 1000);

    }
}


// Canvia el color i emet un so al botó but_num
//
public void but_show(int but_num) {

    if (but_num == 1) {
        l1.setBackgroundResource(color.green_on);
        MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tone_green);
        sound.start();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                l1.setBackgroundResource(color.green_off);
            }
        }, 200);
    } else if (but_num == 2) {
        l2.setBackgroundResource(color.red_on);
        MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tone_red);
        sound.start();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                l2.setBackgroundResource(color.red_off);
            }
        }, 200);
    } else if (but_num == 3) {
        l3.setBackgroundResource(color.yellow_on);
        MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tone_yellow);
        sound.start();
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                l3.setBackgroundResource(color.yellow_off);
            }
        }, 200);
    } else if (but_num == 4) {
        l4.setBackgroundResource(color.blue_on);
        MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tone_blue);
        sound.start();
        // SLEEP HERE ...
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                l4.setBackgroundResource(color.blue_off);
            }
        }, 200);
    }
}
```

Bye !!

Comment: try set to l1, l2 etc. l1.setClickable(true);

Comment: Plz read some online tutorial for Android for beginners first. Specifically you need to learn xml selectors - when used you don't need to change background color manually.

Comment: Hello Anton. Can you recommend some online tutorial for beginners ? Thank's

Comment: @ev3c You should try the official introduction from Google, available here: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Comment: And this article describes precisely how to make button change its background when pressed: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html